# Open URL in new browser with new session and cookies using SWT

Tags: java, browser, swt, swt-awt

I want to open an URL in the external browser with the new session and cookies for the URL. every time the URL is opened it shall be opened in a new browser with new cookies. 
My problem is, whenever I try to open the URL in new browser the old session expires and the old browser window is no more useful. URL parameters will be different every time. I've tried to use the internal browser and well as external browser of SWT. 
tried `Browser.setCookies(value,url);` 
still doesn't work.

For External browser:

```java
public void openUrl(String url){
    IWebBrowser browser = PlatformUI.getWorkbench()
        .getBrowserSupport()
        .createBrowser(IWorkbenchBrowserSupport.AS_EXTERNAL, browserId, name, tooltip); 
    browser.openUrl(url);
}
```

For Internal browser:

```java
public void launchUrl(String url){ 
    Browser browser = (Browser) getBrowserShellNew().getData(BROWSER); // Browser is a static String "BROWSER" 
    browser.setUrl(url); 
}

private Shell getBrowserShellNew(){ 
    Display display=PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay(); 
    Shell shell = new Shell(display); 
    shell.setText("title"); 
    Rectangle screenBounds = null; 
    if (display.getMonitors().length > 1) { 
        screenBounds = display.getMonitors()[1].getBounds();
    } else { 
        screenBounds = display.getMonitors()[0].getBounds(); 
    } 
    shell.setBounds(screenBounds); 
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout()); 
    shell.setMaximized(true); 
    Browser browser = new Browser(shell, SWT.NONE); 
    browser.setMenu(new Menu(browser)); 
    shell.setData(BROWSER, browser); 
    shell.open(); 
    shell.forceActive(); 
    shell.forceFocus(); 
    return shell;
}
```

Reason must be, all browser instance uses the same cookies from the session. Need to somehow create a new session with cookies for every URL launch. Using external browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after some investigation I found the method to achieve this by passing the parameter to IE while launching the URL. as I've already mentioned in the comments to the answer.
Below is the solution that worked for me.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Program Files\\internet explorer\\iexplore.exe -noframemerging \"http://helloworld.com\"");
```

Note: this will only work for IE and windows operating system.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have three options  :

1) `Browser.clearSessions()`

2) `OS.InternetSetOption(0, OS.INTERNET_OPTION_END_BROWSER_SE­SSION, 0, 0);`

3) Delete the content of `%AppData%\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies` if you are on a Windows machine or the corresponding folder in another OS...

Good luck...

Comment: Thanks for your effort and answer, I really appreciate it. I think all the above option will clear the current session too, which will lead to session expiry on the already loaded URL.

Comment: I'll still once try it and check the results. On the other hand I found one solution which works only with the IE browser. Using Runtime class I opened the IE with parameter -noframemerging. This way the new instance of the the browser with new session is created without impacting the existing one.

Comment: I’m confused , Not clear to me if you want to invalidate the session or to keep it...